# How to process two forms in one action bean using Stripes

Tags: java, stripes

I want to use two Stripes:form in one actionbean class. Each form has a Stripes:submit in it. How do I suppose to tell the actionbean which submit is for which form? In other words how to use 'name' or 'id' attribute of Stripes:form in action?

jsp

```
<stripes:form beanclass="com.example.action.StudentActionBean" >
   <stripes:submit name="show" value="Show data"/>
</stripes:form>
<stripes:form beanclass="com.example.action.StudentActionBean" >
   <stripes:submit name="save" value="Save data"/>
</stripes:form>
```

actionbean

```
public Resolution show() {return new ForwardResolution("");}
public Resolution save() {return new ForwardResolution("");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using different name attributes on the submit buttons; for example, I have

```
<stripes:submit
    name="proceed"
    value="Proceed"
/>
```

and in my actionbean I have

```
public Resolution proceed() {
```

So try adding a second form with its submit using a different name and have a method with that name in the actionbean and see if it works.  Also verify that validation works correctly.

Comment: I use different names for each submit, but how to differ two forms that adress same actionbean? I edited my question with an example.